# PySpark DataFrame reads TXT files with the following errors, it drives me crazy

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

Here is my program:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContext

def main():
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[*]")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    sc.setLogLevel("OFF")
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

    rdd = sc.textFile('samples.txt').map(lambda line: line.strip().split(' '))
    print rdd.take(5)
    df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ['raw'])
    df.show(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The file sample.txt seems like:

```
I need your help
Why it has this error
I can not handle it
```

The results of this program are:

```
[[u'I', u'need', u'your', u'help'], [u'Why', u'it', u'has', u'this', u'error'], [u'I', u'can', u'not', u'handle', u'it']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mypath/getIndex.py", line 35, in <module>
main()
  File "/mypath/getIndex.py", line 20, in main
df.show(False)
  File "/Users/lyj/Programs/Apache/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 287, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, truncate))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/Users/lyj/Programs/Apache/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 323, in get_return_value
format(target_id, ".", name, value))
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o65.showString. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method showString([class java.lang.Boolean, class java.lang.Boolean]) does not exist
at
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
at
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:272)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:128)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)



Process finished with exit code 1
```

What's wrong with this problem? I have never met this error before, and I think it's because of Pyspark DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Dataframe requires an rdd with constant number of columns, replace your sample.txt

```
Please I need your help
Why it has this error
I can not handle it
```

then

```
df.show()
```

outputs

```
+------+---+----+------+-----+
|   raw| _2|  _3|    _4|   _5|
+------+---+----+------+-----+
|Please|  I|need|  your| help|
|   Why| it| has|  this|error|
|     I|can| not|handle|   it|
+------+---+----+------+-----+
```

note that you renamed only the first column

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem might be the code "df.show(False)", it should be df.show(truncate=False).